# How to send two values with MPI broadcast without an error 11?

Tags: c, runtime-error, mpi

I'm trying to send the widht and height of a pic that is read by the process 0 and send it to all the processes, but a runtime error 11 appears. (The func stbi_load gets the widht and height)

```
pixel* pixels_in;

int in_width;
int in_height;
int channels;

if(rank==0){
    pixels_in = (pixel *) stbi_load(argv[1], &in_width, &in_height, &channels, STBI_rgb_alpha);
    if (pixels_in == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
}
MPI_Bcast(&in_width,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(&in_height,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf("Image dimensions: %dx%d\n", in_width, in_height);
```

The execution:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGPhZ.png)

Image dimensions: 1024x1024                                                                                            Image dimensions: 1024x1024                                                                                            Image dimensions: 1024x1024                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Signal 11 received                                                                                                                                                                                                                            Signal 11 received                                                                                                    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------                                          One of the processes started by mpirun has exited with a nonzero exit                                                  code.  This typically indicates that the process finished in error.                                                    If your process did not finish in error, be sure to include a "return                                                  0" or "exit(0)" in your C code before exiting the application.                                                                                                                                                                                PID 4256 failed on node n0 (127.0.0.1) with exit status 11.                                                            -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Please edit your question with a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Does your program start with `MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);` and end with `MPI_Finalize();` ? See this [helloworld example](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~pollock/367/manual/node18.html) for instance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.